# The vertical lines of the table of the last cell on the page are not drawn to the end

Tags: java, itext

Sometimes will it be happens, sometimes not. The construction of the table is too complex. It generated from xml/xslt transformation. Why the table has this form ? Simple I did not find other solution for width inner tables.

You can see trouble in the screenshot, why it happens and how it fix ?

ps. itext and xmlparser v.5.5.11

[image]

Comment: please just add the screenshot here, and not a link=/

Comment: thanks, for edit, I can't edit because low reputation

Answer (score 0):

I am removed the html construction like on the screenshot and made more simple/flat tables with rowspans and colspans. Also I made extends Table class and override end() method. Also I added some better calculation for relative widths of the table and use it new value. Now it's getting a bit better, but not perfect.